# Can I carry 30 comics with me while traveling from the USA to India?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, legal

I will be traveling from the USA to India. And my son has told me to buy quite a lot of comics for him. So my question is, can I carry around 30 to 50 comics while traveling from the USA to India without facing any customs charges?

Comment: Any reason you are bringing them from US ? Which brand i.e. DC, Marvel etc ?  Did you check if they aren't available in India ?

Comment: It's mostly DC Sliver age comics. And no, these comics aren't available in India.

Comment: Duty payable also depends on value. Are these comics particularly valuable?

Comment: Be careful with the weight of your suitcases, paper is heavy.

Comment: Nah. Most of them aren't valuable. Only 5 comics are some key issues. Got a lot of 30 comics for 20$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://www.cybex.in/indian-custom-duty/Printed-Books-Brochures-Leaflets-Similar-Hs-Code-4901.aspx) you need to pay 10% customs duty on bringing in printed books, assume that is the classification of comics.

But no duty is payable because of exemption provided [here](http://www.cbec.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/customs/cs-tariff2015-16/csgen-exmptn165.pdf).

> 272. 4901 10 10, 4901 91 00 4901 99 00
>
> Printed books (including covers for or printed books) and printed manuals,in bound form or in loose-leaf form with binder, executed on paper or any other material including transparencies.

[SOURCE](https://spicyip.com/2016/11/is-the-import-of-books-into-india-too-taxing-debunking-the-myth.html)